# debug mysql crash

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have a production server which I am managing and I have been running a rails application on this server. The issue has happened twice in the past month or so and I am not sure how to debug this.

MySQL server crashes and when I check the status of the service it responds that it is waiting for a stop

Also any other services I have running such as delayed_job worker which send emails from the application at a set interval also stop responding.

With my limited expertise in the server management area, I am completely lost as to how to debug this issue.

I am using ununtu 12.04 OS with apache and passenger setup with mysql as db.

Comment: Please update this ticket with your mysql error log.  What version of MySQL are you using?  Please include any other specific errors.

Comment: MySQL Version = 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

Comment: Error Log Blank

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has an article called: [What to Do If MySQL Keeps Crashing](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/crashing.html), which is pretty thorough.

One of the first things that you should do is check the MySQL error logs. Try taking a look the contents of `/var/log/mysql.err`.

Comment: Well Error log is blank so that leads me no where, let me read the article in detail. :)